# Woocommerce Product Page: how to change position of 'short description', 'price' and 'variation description'

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In a Woocommerce Product Page: how to change position of 'short description', 'price' and 'variation description'?

I need to put the 'Product short description' above the 'Price' and the 'Variation Description' just below the Price.

**This is what I have right now:**

[image]

**And this is what I need:**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you look at https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.8.0/templates/content-single-product.php#L47 you'll see that the product summary is constructed using hooks with different priorities.

&

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.8.0/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php#L65

so you can just swap the values

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 20 );

function move() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'move' );
```

Answer (score 0):

normaly you will find different hooks / different priorities in the templates folder of woocommerce.

In the content-single-product.php inside you will find some comments like:

```
   * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
   * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
   * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
   * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
```

To modify create an new ordering in the functions.php of the child theme like this

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 30);
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 20);
```